# Conditional Partitioning of Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partition, partition-by

I have a 2-column dataframe such as:

```
col1 | col2
------------
a1   |   b1
------------
a2   |   b1
------------
a3   |   b2
------------
a1   |   b2
------------
a1   |   b3
------------
```

I partition this dataframe using a random number generation:

```
df = df.withColumn("part", (rand() * num_partitions).cast("int"))
df.write.partitionBy("part").mode("overwrite").parquet("/address/")
```

However, with this partitioning, there is no guarantee that all rows where `col1=a1` will be allocated in one partition. Is there any way to have this guarantee while partitioning the dataframe?

Comment: Why not just `partitionBy("col1")`?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy because the distribution of values in `col1` is very skewed. For some values, we only have few rows, for others we could have up to a million. Hence, partitions will not be equally sized.

Comment: Well, in that case allocating all rows with col1=a1 into one partition is something to avoid, no?

Comment: That should be fine as long as the size of all partitions are roughly the same. We don't want to have one partition with size 10^6 and another with size 10. However, if all partitions have size 10^6 we should be fine.

Comment: I guess you would need to count `col1` values and manually assign partition numbers if you want both grouping and equal sizes.

Comment: And what is the total count of the dataset and number of distinct col1 values?

Answer (score 0):

You can repartition the dataset on `part` such as `repartition(num_partitions, "part")`, this will reduce the skew along your partition column `col1`. After while writing you will specify `col1` in the `partitionBy` expression.

```
df.write.partitionBy("col1").mode("overwrite").parquet("/address/")
```